# How can I bundle an iPhone/iPad app with an ebook on iBooks?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ibooks

I am creating a universal iOS app, which I would like to distribute with certain eBooks published by other authors. When a user purchases specific books, I would like to give them a free download of my app. For example, if my app is a glossary of statistical terms, I would like to offer my app for free when a user purchases a book such as "Statistics 101" or "Statistical Analysis of Stochastic Equations".

I am willing to work with the author of the book to do what is necessary. But what I want to find out is how can I link the eBook purchase on iBooks with a free app download. If it means generating unique promo-code like numbers to redeem, how do I generate hundreds of them and have them individually served out?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  But you can do the reverse, embed a pdf inside of an application.

There's really no mechanism to do coupons or special discount codes in iTunes for apps.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the App only work after the entry of a Promo code, but Apple will not approve it.

With a native App, its nearly impossible. But it should work with an Web-App. Is this an option?

Otherwise you could bundle the ebook with your App.

Comment: Good ideas. It needs to be a native app. And I want to give the app away with multiple books.

Comment: @user683178 You could either make the eBooks inAppPurchases and let the User import them in for Example iBooks or you could use Promo codes. For the last option, I suggest to add some free content, because the chance that Apple approves it is much higher then.